# Starting a Spark Session without executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a use-case where I need to use some Spark's API without actually performing any data processing. For example: I want to read the schema of some Hive table with `spark.table(table_name).schema`.

I want the process to be fast and lightweight. Specifically, I want to avoid the relatively long wait time to get the resources when starting. Is there a way to get a limited Spark Session with just the driver JVM and no executors at all?

The best I managed is this, but I wanted to see if I can make it even lighter:

```py
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .master("local[1]")
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "1")
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "1")
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "450m")
    .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "0")
    .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
    .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
)
```

Comment: Can you use Hive client instead? Or do you have to have Spark?

Comment: This is a simplified example. I actually need more than just Hive metastore access. For example, I need to use some functions from `pyspark.sql.functions` that need to access the underlying JVM process, which only starts when I launch a Spark Session

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear up your line of thought:

In `local mode`, the `Driver` and `Executors` are created in a `single JVM`. But there are no real Executors; there are just N cores for the Spark App to use.

So you are good with local[1], but you need not state this executore-params.